# Replace div with another div when clicked

Tags: javascript

Now what I want is #youtube to show at all times, but if you click on it i want to transform it to #embed. Cant get it to work. and what I mean by that is that it dont do what i just explained. Nothing happens.

```
<div id="youtube" onclick="replace()" style="display:block">
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$id.'/1.jpg">
<span class="title"><font color="#999">YouTube&trade; Video:</font> '.$title.'</span>
<span class="views">Views: '.number_format($views).'</span>
<span class="description">'.$desc.'</span>
</div>

// show this only if they clicked on #youtube
<div id="embed" onclick="replace()" style="display:none">
<object width="425" height="344">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1?fs=1"</param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1?fs=1"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" width="425" height="344">
</embed>
</object>
     </div>
```

JS:

```
function replace() {
document.getElementById(youtube).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(embed).style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing quotes around your div names in `getElementById`:

```
function replace() {
    document.getElementById("youtube").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("embed").style.display="block";
}
```

`getElementById` accepts a string, embed is an identifier name, you need to use a string literal by wrapping it with ticks.

Answer (score 2):

Just quote the name of your div

```
document.getElementById('youtube').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('embed').style.display="block";
```